# How to convert command line output from Freeling to consumable array

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby, nlp, freeling

I am using Ruby for this. 
Freeling (a NLP tool) has a shallow parser which returns a string like this for the text "I just read the book, the grasshopper lies heavy" when I run a shallow parsing command.

```
a = <<EOT
S_[
  sn-chunk_[
    +(I i PRP -)
  ]
  adv_[
    +(just just RB -)
  ]
  vb-chunk_[
    +(read read VB -)
  ]
  sn-chunk_[
    (the the DT -)
    +n-chunk_[
      (book book NN -)
      +n-chunk_[
        +(The_Grasshopper_Lies_Heavy the_grasshopper_lies_heavy NP -)
      ]
    ]
  ]
  st-brk_[
    +(. . Fp -)
  ]
]

EOT
```

I want to get the following array from this:

```
["I", "just", "read", "the book The Grasshopper Lies Heavy","."]
```

(I want to merge the words that are under a tree and have it as a single array element.)

So far, I have written this much:

```
b = a.gsub(/.*\[/,'[').gsub(/.*\+?\((\w+|.) .*/,'\1').gsub(/\n| /,"").gsub("_","")
```

which returns

```
[[I][just][read][the[book[The Grasshopper Lies Heavy]]][.]]
```

So, how can i get the desired array?

Comment: Are you sure the API you are using cannot output the tokens list? Acc. to the docs, try `--outf token` if you are using a command line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn't. 'shallow' is one of the result options, if i do the other option called 'tagged' it just tags each word/named entity separately and i don't get the tree for "the book The Grasshopper Lies Heavy".

Comment: With the regex approach, how can you differentiate between a real `_` and the one introduced by Freeling tree builder? You are now removing all underscores. Or will there be no underscores in the output tree?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there wont be. but i think that is a minor problem i can do \w_\w or something like that. but the main problem is converting the thing to a consumable array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your solution so far:

```
result = a.gsub(/.*\[/,'[').gsub(/.*\+?\((\w+|.) .*/,'\1').gsub(/\n| /,"").gsub("_"," ")
result.split('][').map { |s| s.gsub(/\[|\]/, ' ').strip }     # ["I", "just", "read", "the book The Grasshopper Lies Heavy", "."]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call FreeLing from Ruby via the API, you can get the tree and traverse it at will.

If you are using the output of the command-line program and loading it into Ruby as a string, it may be easier to call it with option "--output conll" which will produce a tabular format easier to deal with.

Comment: i just did that but it didn't work: this works ` "#{analyzer_path} -f #{cfg_path} --inpf plain --outf shallow" ` this doesn't `"#{analyzer_path} -f #{cfg_path} --inpf plain --outf shallow --output conll"`

Comment: option "--output conll" only works in version 4.0 newer, and it seems you are using 3.x